# Import old es5 file with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am trying to include a minified javascript file directly, it works perfectly fine but i do get warning because the old es5 script does not export its global variable.

**Property 'fire' does not exist on type**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';

import Swal from './external/sweetalert2.all.min.js';

$('[test-btn]').on('click', (e) => {
    Swal.fire({
        position: 'top-end',
        icon: 'success',
        title: 'Your work have been saved!',
        showConfirmButton: false,
        timer: 1500
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Are you writing JS or TS? Because it looks like this is an error message generated by VSCode, if you enable [checkJs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig), which is effectively Typescript-like type checking. Just disable it, and you should be fine (unless you intend to properly type out all your JS code). Otherwise, you can manually add type definitions, as explained here: https://medium.com/@steveruiz/using-a-javascript-library-without-type-declarations-in-a-typescript-project-3643490015f3

Comment: I am writing TS, thank you very much for you're answer, I will try both the VS code setting and also try adding a type definition

Answer (score 1):

My solution was doing this variant

[image]